# Indiscernible sequences in o-minimal structures

Tags: model-theory, o-minimal

Is there an explicit characterisation of indiscernible sequences in o-minimal structures ? Say for expansions of the reals or $R_{an}$ ?

Is there a characterisation of o-minimality in terms of properties of indiscernible sequences or types ? Or at least some nice properties.

Here is an example of an oversimplified question. Is it true that a sequence in an elementary extension of the reals is indiscernible iff it or its inverse ( meaning $1/x_n$ ) is monotone, ACF-indiscernible, and fits into an infenitesimal neighbourhood, and converges fast enough in some sense ?

Comment: Indiscernible sequences in RCF were characterized by David Rosemthal in his phd thesis. I found a copy here: http://www.borisbukh.org/rosenthal_thesis.pdf

Comment: Thanks, that's part of what i was looking for.  Do you know if these results would apply to o-minimal extensions of RCF ?

Comment: I haven't read the thesis, so I can't say how much would generalize. But it seems very likely that arguments of a similar form would work to give a similar characterization.